# Angular: access ngResources from a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to access some ngResources from a directive is this possible?

Basically my directive $scope has an object which points to other via ids, those other objects can be populated via existing ngResource. I'd like to load them to render them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass $resource, or your own $resource-based service to the directive.

```
.directive('myDirective', function($resource, MyService) {

});
```

Comment: On behalf of [Kurt Mueller](http://stackoverflow.com/users/527472/kurt-mueller): This works through Dependency Injection. AngularJS will look for MyService and when it finds it, inject it into the directive.